# Update Single Field on Domain Save

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

The [`save()`](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html) method seems to replace an entire document/record in my database. If I know the primary key of a document in my database, what is the best way in Grails for me to update a single field on that document without first querying the database using `get()`?

For instance, I don't like the following code because it executes two queries when all I want to do is to update `myField`.

```
def key = "foo"
def doc = MyDomain.get(key)  // This is the query I want to eliminate
doc.myField = "bar"
doc.save()
```

In situations where I know the primary key, I want to simply update a single field, similarly to how Ruby on Rails leverages the [`ActionModel.update_attribute()`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute) method.

Even though my specific database is MongoDB, I think the question is applicable to any database, SQL or NoSQL. If the database supports the ability to update just a single field on one record via one query, using Grails can I avoid the extra `get()` query to retrieve a full record from the database?

Comment: You cannot use .save() for single property/partial update. Only option that i can think of is executeUpdate.

Comment: use update method instead : https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/   save method will upsert not update